# Using longitude/latitude to calculate OSGR

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

Our database currently stores 2 values - the longitude and the latitude. E.g.:

```
Longitude: -0.310150 N
Latitude: 52.688930 W
```

What we would like to do now is convert these values into the Ordanance Survey Grid Reference (OSGR) for British locations. Is there an easy way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Lots of info [in this PDF](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/information/coordinatesystemsinfo/guidecontents/index.html) but no simple mapping I can see: interesting map page 35, appendix C looks most promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for this conversion is pretty complex because osgr and gps use different projections

[This page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html) provides an example in C that should be easy enough to re write in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Twelve47, this looks very useful. Looks hard to understand but I'll try it out.

Comment: If it's any help, when I batch-converted our OSGB references to latitude and longitude, I did it using the open source PROJ.4 tool, part of the [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) toolkit. (It also translates the other way round.) Might be something there that'll help you.